# How to find all matches of a pattern in a string using regex

Tags: regex, groovy

If I have a string like:

```
s = "This is a simple string 234 something else here as well 4334
```

and a regular expression like:

```
regex = ~"[0-9]{3}"
```

How can I extract all the words from the string using that regex? In this case `234` and `433`?

Answer (score 28):

You can use `CharSequence.findAll`:

```
def triads = s.findAll("[0-9]{3}")

assert triads == ['234', '433']
```

[Latest documentation of `CharSequence.findAll`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#findAll(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: [Link to documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#findAll(java.lang.String))

Comment: should be `s.findAll(/[0-9]{3}/)`

Comment: Makes no difference....  THat's exactly the same call, just with a different String delimiting character 

Comment: The are no quotes... Anyway, hope you feel better after spreading the joy

Answer (score 14):

You have to use capturing groups. You can check groovy's documentation about it:

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html

For instance, you can use this code:

```
s = "This is a simple string 234 something else here as well 4334"
regex = /([0-9]{3})/

matcher = ( s=~ regex )

if (matcher.matches()) {
    println(matcher.getCount()+ " occurrence of the regular expression was found in the string.");
    println(matcher[0][1] + " found!")
}
```

As a side note:

```
m[0] is the first match object.
m[0][0] is everything that matched in this match.
m[0][1] is the first capture in this match.
m[0][n] is the n capture in this match.
```

Comment: `matcher.matches()` is intended to be used for matching complete strings, using a different syntax. I just used `if (matcher.getCount > 0)` to check for a match instead.

Comment: @neves have just fixed it

Answer (score 12):

You could do something like this.

```
def s = "This is a simple string 234 something else here as well 4334" 
def m = s =~ /[0-9]{3}/
(0..<m.count).each { println m[it][0] }
```

**Output** ( [**Working Demo**](http://ideone.com/q3EZpS) )

```
234
433
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `m[it][0]` ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've mixed it up with the regexp which captures groups. Your solution is simpler - vote up :) Btw. you can iterate through matches with: `m.each { print it + '\n' }`.

Comment: Using this , how do I ensure that the regex at least matched something? Before I iterate through the matcher.

Answer (score 0):

```
def INPUT= 'There,once,was,a man,from,"the , extremely,,,,bad  .,,  , edge",of 
the,"universe, ultimately,, is mostly",empty,,,space';
def REGEX = ~/(\"[^\",]+),([^\"]+\")/; 
def m = (INPUT =~ REGEX);
while (true) {
   m = (INPUT =~ REGEX);
   if (m.getCount()>0) {
       INPUT = INPUT.replaceAll(REGEX,'$1!-!$2');
        System.out.println(INPUT );
   } else {
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).