# Regex to find all matches of from a string

Tags: python, regex, substring

I have the string:

`TEXT OF SWITZERLAND CASABLANCA, 2041 Cash 1234e`

I want to extract all alphanumeric values (**digits compulsory**) with length of at least 4, with or without the inclusion of the special characters `/\_:.\-|`

Below is the Regex that I have tried.

`(?=.{4,}$)(?=.*[0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9/\\_:.\-|]+)$`

But this only captures the required pattern if it is last in the string.
I want to capture all the values. In this case `2041` and `1234e`.

I have tried solutions from the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558031/how-to-find-all-matches-of-a-pattern-in-a-string-using-regex) and a few more but none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\b(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9/\\_:.\-|]{4,}\b
```

Try this.`$` is causing only the last match to be found.`\b` will mark the word boundary and you get all the matches.See demo

https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/15#python

Comment: If two alphanumeric strings are present it picks only the first one.
example string, `Philippe Columbus 57s2 COLVMBVS CCSTRH8 Stainless Steel`

Comment: @Vaulstein it picks both.See here https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/16 use `re.findall`

Comment: @Vaulstein try `(?:^|(?<=\s))(?=[a-zA-Z/\\_:.\-|]*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9/\\_:.\-|]{4,}(?=\s|$)` See demo. https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/19

Comment: @Vaulstein this will find words which are at start or at end or have spaces around it + other conditions

Answer (score 1):

Adding to VKS's answer, the regex could not match the string `ABSTRD.910.824`

I tried this and it worked perfectly.

Regex:
`\b(?=[a-zA-Z/\\_:\-.|]*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9/\\_:\-.|]{4,}\b`

Comment: You can also try the new one