# Unable to Get More than 1 Match From String Using Regex

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have been stuck looking around for all sorts of solutions to this problem and I have tried multiple suggestions like this one [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558031/how-to-find-all-matches-of-a-pattern-in-a-string-using-regex) and have been unsuccessful. The task is relatively simply and I have been successful in grabbing a single match so I know my regex is correct. I am working with Groovy inside of my Jenkins Pipeline script

Here is the problem, I have a file I read from like the following

```
<log><logentry revision="4813"><msg>nvcs-0909 haha nvpl-6700</msg></logentry></log>
```

All I want to do is grab the **nvcs-0909** and **nvpl-6700** and place them as the currentBuild.description. I can do it for one, but can't get multiple entries

Here is what I have so far

```
textOfFile = readFile("..\\builds\\$BUILD_NUMBER\\changelog0.xml")
regex = /[Nn][Vv]..[-\s]{1,3}\d+/
allIssues = (textOfFile =~ regex)
```

And when I print allIssues I get

```
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[Nn][Vv]..[-\s]{1,3}\d+ region=0,377 lastmatch=]
```

How can I get this to work?

I have also tried

```
allIssues = textOfFile.findAll(regex)
```

And that fails as well but

```
allIssues = textOfFile.find(regex)
```

works and I get the first match I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was one I faced before but was hidden because I added a try/catch this time around and not earlier with the find method. The current code was

```
def textOfFile
try {
    textOfFile = readFile("..\\builds\\$BUILD_NUMBER\\changelog0.xml")
    List<String> allIssues = textOfFile.findAll("[Nn][Vv]..[-\\s]{1,3}\\d+")
    issueDescription = ""

    for(int i = 0; i < allIssues.size(); i++)
        issueDescription += allIssues[i].toUpperCase() + (i < allIssues.size() - 1 ? ", ":"")

    currentBuild.description = issueDescription
}
catch(e) {
    echo "ERROR"
}
```

Since I was trying to wrap my head around what in the world was going on I printed the error message with

```
println e.getMessage()
```

Inside the catch block and it gave the following message

```
Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods findAll java.lang.String
```

I ran into this message before and solved it with the help of [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/). But Jenkins wouldn't give me the option to add permissions and you can't manually add them yourself in (**Manage Jenkins -> In-Process Script Approval**).

So I commented out the try/catch, ran the script, let Jenkins catch the exception and I was given the option to allow my script to use the findAll method. Then I ran it one more time and it worked perfectly and re-wrapped the code in the try/catch.

I am guessing that the notification mechanism for allowing you to allow method permissions in Jenkins is triggered when your script throws the exception and never catches it..? Anyways it's working perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 0):

works fine:

```
def textOfFile = '''<log><logentry revision="4813"><msg>nvcs-0909 haha nvpl-6700</msg></logentry></log>'''
def regex = /[Nn][Vv]..[-\s]{1,3}\d+/

println (textOfFile =~ regex).findAll()
```

result:

```
[nvcs-0909, nvpl-6700]
```