# Groovy, how to get unique values from a list?

Tags: groovy

In my code below I get following results:
res = [[ aaa ,  aaa ], [ bbb ,  bbb ], [ ccc ,  ccc ]]
res size = 48

But what I expect is:
res = [aaa, bbb, ccc]
res size = 3

Could someone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong here?

`

```
def str = "123  START aaa END  456 START bbb END 789 START ccc END"
def res

res = getTextBetweenTwoStrings(str)

log.info("res = "  + res)
log.info("res size = "  + res.size())

def  getTextBetweenTwoStrings(String str)
{
        def matchStr =  /(?<=START)([\s\S]*?)(?=END)/ 
        String  findmatchStr = (str =~ /$matchStr/).findAll()
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`findAll(CharSequence regex)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#findAll(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
def matches = str.findAll(/(?<=START)([\s\S]*?)(?=END)/)

assert matches == [" aaa ", " bbb ", " ccc "] // note the spaces are from your regex
```

You can also use edit your regex to remove the capturing group:

```
assert (str =~ /(?<=START)[\s\S]*?(?=END)/).findAll() == [" aaa ", " bbb ", " ccc "]
```

A helpful [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558031/how-to-find-all-matches-of-a-pattern-in-a-string-using-regex)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes in your code:

1. your method returned a `String`, although it should be returning a `List`, that's why you get the size of a `List.toString()` representation, rather than `List.size()`
2. The `findAll()` method returns a complex list of list, containing each matching group of your regex.

The right way to put your coude would be:

```
def str = "123  START aaa END  456 START bbb END 789 START ccc END"
def res = getTextBetweenTwoStrings str

assert ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'] == res
assert 3 == res.size()

def  getTextBetweenTwoStrings(String str)
{
   (str =~ /(?<=START)\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*(?=END)/ ).findAll()*.last()
}
```

Also note the `\s*` around the group to trim the strings.